# TeXstudio cannot find my TeXlive installation

Tags: texlive, texstudio, linux

OS: Manjaro Linux 21.0

TeX Live: 2020

Texstudio: 3.1.1

Installation: via `install-tl` on `/usr/local/texlive/2020` see https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Issue: I set the tex command in my PATH and texstudio can find my tex when I start it from command line but if I open texstudio on Desktop it cannot find my tex installation.

If I add it in settings it can run `xelatex` but cannot find `extractbb`

Can I install texlive in `/usr/bin/`? If can, how to?

Comment: Exactly **where** did you add tl20 to your path? If bashrc then that is not enough if you start the editor from a menu or by double clicking a file. Add it to your dot profile as well, log out and in again (the file is only read at login). This is sadly a very common problem

Comment: Is the path correct in Options >> Configure TeXstudio >> Commands? If not,  in the "pdfLaTeX" line click on "Select Program" button and select `pdflatex` in `opt/texbin` folder

Comment: Do you mean I can write in `.profile` (I currently do not have this file) exactly the same as in `.bashrc`? @daleif

Comment: Yes, put those lines in `.profile` log out and in again. I'm not familiar with Manjaro Linux, if this doesn't work you'll need to find something similar for Manjaro. Any change in bashrc is never seen by a process started via, say, a menu. And bash is not used either when the editor calls larex.

Comment: Yes I put it in my `.profile` like this @daleif:
```
PATH=/home/firestar/.texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/home/firestar/.texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/home/firestar/.texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH

```
But TexStudio still cannot found it. See https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1549

Comment: Did you log out and in again after editing the dot profile file?

Comment: Yes, and I reboot and shut down for several times.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `sudo perl install-tl -gui`, choose `Create symlinks in standard directories:`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/207724)

Comment: @Roland: I have edited this answer to provide an answer to the question.