# TeX Studio won't recognize biblatex package

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, ubuntu, linux

I am using TeX Studio on a linux computer (Ubuntu 18.04) with texlive. Inside TeX Studio, Whenever I try to build a document that uses the `biblatex` package, I get the error "File `biblatex.sty` not found". But I know that I have the `biblatex` package on my computer, because the same problem does not arise when compiling documents from the command line. Most other packages seem to be recognized without trouble.

I have checked that I indeed have `biblatex` by typing `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` on the command line, which gave me `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`.

I have also tried to make sure that TeX Studio is seeing the correct installation of TeX on my computer by going into `Options > Configure TeX Studio > Build > Build Options > Commands ($PATH)` and entering the location at which the latest version of texlive lives, which for me is `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/` (i.e. this is what comes up when I type `which pdflatex` at the command line.

I recently updated my texlive distrbution to the 2021 version, and al re-installed TeXStudio (now 4.1.2). None of this has changed things. I suspect that this might have something to do with TeX Studio continuing to use some old version of latex which came with Ubuntu, but I was hoping that adding the new installation to `$PATH` should have fixed that issue.

Comment: Check the log files of a minimal example. They will tell you the path of article.cls and so which TeX system is used.

Comment: I would guess that you forgot to put the texlive 2021 bin directory in your PATH and so texstudio is picking up the linux system tex from ./usr/bin, especially if you start the editor from the desktop you need to make sure the PATH is set before the desktop starts

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- I looked at the log file of a minimal example and you are right, it seems like TeX Studio is using TeX Live 2017 (which I think comes bundled with Ubuntu), and the path of the article class file is `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`. My preferred installation of TeX Live is in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/...`. How do I get TeX Studio to use the correct version?

Comment: no idea, I'm on windows. Check the settings in texstudio, perhaps there is a path somewhere. And check how you open texstudio.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I export `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` to `PATH` in a bash file where I keep all my modifications to the `PATH` variable. I do start TeX Studio from the desktop interface of Ubuntu, so I just restarted my computer but that makes no difference.

Comment: I suspect you are setting the path too late set it in your .profile or .bash_profile or whatever you use check the log file for any simple latex document started from the editor: does it use texlive 2021 and article.cls from /usr/local/texlive or does it use an older tex and article.cls from /usr/share ah you did that already, sorry!

Comment: Update: the problem doesn't arise if I start TeX Studio from the command line (by typing `texstudio`). If I start from the command line, the log file shows that it is indeed using the correct (2021) version of TeX Live. Thank you both!
But  @DavidCarlisle how do I ensure that the PATH is set before desktop starts?

Comment: set it in .profile or .bash_profile should work

Comment: I set the PATH in a file called `~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: the details of which files are read in which order is very system specific (and I don't have an ubuntu desktop to test) it is now unrelated to tex really as it's a general unbuntu question of where to set the environment for the desktop it would apply tp all programs not just texlive

Comment: your question is same as this one which gets the same answer in comments, use `.profile` (unfortunately the actual posted answer there is wrong) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588337/texstudio-cannot-find-my-texlive-installation

Comment: Modifying PATH inside `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bash_aliases` fixed the issue. Now TeX Studio recognizes the more recent version of TeX Live even when opened from Desktop.